# Is truncating a discrete probability mass function possible?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have random variable X, and probability distribution:

$P[X = A] = .4$
$P[X = B] = .3$ 
$P[X = C] = .2$ 
$P[X = D] = .1$

I want to create a conditional probability with event F.
Where F is the event that $F=A, F =B$. Can I truncate the discrete PMF so that:

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{P[X = x, x=A,x=B]}{P[x=A,x=B]}$?

Or can I simply do P[X(A+B)]=1

P[A'] = XP[A]

P[B'] = XP[B]

Comment: Several typos in "Where B is the event that A<=F<=B".

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is the event that $X=A$ or $X=B$, then $$P(X=A\mid F)=\frac{P(X=A)}{P(X=A)+P(X=B)}=\frac{.4}{.4+.3}=\frac47,$$ and $$ P(X=B\mid F)=\frac{P(X=B)}{P(X=A)+P(X=B)}=\frac{.3}{.4+.3}=\frac37.$$